# How can I create individual routes in a React application for each item in a list of data fetched from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

How can I make an API call for product information when clicking on each product, considering I have a list of products and their respective routes in a React application?

```
function App() {
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://172.17.17.101:8088/api/fa/Nas/Product/GetProductNameList")
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        setProductList(res.data.messageItems[0].data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ListItem productList={productList} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ListItem ({ productList }) {
  return (
    <List
      sx={{
        width: "100%",
        maxWidth: "40%",
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        position: "relative",
        overflow: "auto",
        maxHeight: "80vh",
        "& ul": { padding: 0 },
      }}
    >
      {productList.map((product) => (
        <ListItemButton key={product.productId}>
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemText primary={product.productName} />
          </ListItem>
        </ListItemButton>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider

1. product listing
2. product detail

let's go through both of them one by one

1. product listing

You get the product list from api and you show case the list to frontend, where the api gives you all the required data about all the product and a unique id of the product with which the product is uniquely identified.

2. product detail

here what you have is a single object with detail of single product, for which the api call would be different.

Now, here are two pages as we show, to achieve this functionality what you need to do is to set up the routes

I hope you know how to use routing in react, if you don't then we can work on that too no worries but if you do then move to below steps

run:
npm i react-router-dom

wrap your app component like this:

```
 ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Add routes to your app:

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/products" element={<Product />} />
      <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
</Routes>
```

here, when the any of the product inside the list is clicked it will be redirected to products/id where the id is the id of that product with which it's uniquely identified.

ex.

all the product in product list will have this so as any of the product is clicked the routes will be changed according to the id of the product

```
<Link to={`/products/${product.id}`}>
 Your Code Goes Here
</Link>
```

This was about the product listing now let's move on to the product detail page

use the below code to fetch the id from url,

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

use this id and append it to your api call as per your api call you will receive a single product with all it's detail fetched with it's id which is unique.